# Android : Value of check box in SharedPreferences is not reflected at UI

Tags: android

In onResume of my PrefereneActivity, I have the following code :

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    boolean isEnabled = sp.getBoolean("check_enabled", false);
```

The value of isEnabled is false, however, in the UI the checkbox is still shown as selected. Why is it so?

Answer (score 0):

Do you call `mCheckBox.setChecked(isEnabled);` in `onResume()` of your activity?
`mCheckBox` is your checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not using Editor.commit(); after putting the values..

```
Editor editor = mypreferences.edit();
editor.putBoolean("check_enabled", checkboxb.isChecked());
editor.commit();
```